# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module' при импорте собственных модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, macos, модули

Всем привет! Имеется структура:

```
|--folder/
    |--a.py
|--main.py
```

При загрузке модуля 'main' в модуль 'a'

```
#a.py
import main
```

возникает ошибка - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'.

PyCharm с данной задачей справляется, а VSCode нет.
В чем дело?

Comment: Зависит от того, из какой папки вы запускаете скрипт `a.py`. Скорее всего, PyCharm запускает из корневой папки, а VSCode из папки `folder`.

Comment: Нужно открыть в vscode папку, где все это у вас лежит (а не отдельный файл), тогда все будет работать

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych я запускаю через кнопку 'Run Python File' находясь в коренной папке. То же самое происходит, если перейти в папку 'folder'

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо в системные пути добавить абсолютный путь к каталогу в котором лежит `main.py` Например он лежит в каталоге `mod`. По пути `/home/andrei/projects/mod`

[image: explorer]

Тогда в файле `a.py` напишем следующий код:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/andrei/projects/mod')
import main
```

Чтобы не хардкодить можно сделать вот так:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import main
```

Для проверки успешности импорта в файле `main.py` пропишем следующий код:

```
print('Hello!!!')
```

И запустим в консоли файл `a.py` В консоли напечатается Hello!!!

Comment: @AntonMigulev Дописал код без хардкода.

Comment: спасибо. Тем не менее, интересно почему необходимо делать данную процедуру? можно ли обойтись без нее, прописал где-то в настройках? PyCharm же как-то работает без нее

Comment: @AntonMigulev PyCharm автоматически за вас добавляет в системные пути необходимый путь. А на сервере Вам нужно будет прописать этот путь. Вы также можете изменить архитектуру так чтобы не требовалось использовать относительные пути в импортах. Переместите файл main.py в папку folder и импортируйте без танцев с бубном.